# How to pass sql file into node-mssql

Tags: sql, node.js, file, node-mssql

How do we pass external sql file into node-mssql query

I tried to pass in file as shown in below code but its not working. I tried concatenating string still it did not work

```
request.query(query + `IN ('${serverName.join("','")}')`)
```

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const config = require('../Util/config')
const fs = require('fs')
const log = require('../Util/log')

module.exports = function (req, res, viewFile, next) {
  log(req)

  const query = fs.readFileSync('./sql/Local-admin-user.sql', 'utf8')
  // console.log(query);

  const serverName = "'" + req.body.server_name.split(/\r?\n/).join("','") + "'"
  console.log(serverName)

  var dbConn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
  dbConn.connect().then(function () {
    var request = new sql.Request(dbConn)
    request.query(query)
      .then(output => {
        let dataSet = output.recordset
          console.log(dataSet)
        dbConn.close()
      })
      .catch(err => {
        let dataSet = err
        console.log('error from routes.js', dataSet)
       dbConn.close()
      })
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Local-admin-user.sql

```sql
select servername,
username,
groupname from GROUP_MEMBERS_DATA where servername in (@servers)
```

I am getting error like

```sh
Incorrect syntax near servername
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it like this

```
--remove "in (@servers)" from Local-admin-user.sql
--Example
select servername, username, groupname 
from GROUP_MEMBERS_DATA where servername
```

in javascript add below code

```
 const serverName = "'" + req.body.server_name.split(/\r?\n/).join("','") + "'"
 const sqlquery = (query + ` IN (${serverName})`)
```

So output of sqlquery will be as below

```
select servername, username, groupname 
from GROUP_MEMBERS_DATA where servername in ('server1','server2')
```